# Not getting output

Tags: c

I was trying to scan a string input from the user and then print it in the next line, but I'm not able to figure out, as I'm new to coding, why it is showing no output! Below is the code-

```
main()
{
    char* w1,w2,w3,e1,e2,e3;
    printf("List of Words");
    printf("\tMeanings");
    scanf("%s",&w1);
    printf("\n%s",w1);
    getch();
}
```

I expected w1 to print under "List of Words" but it isn't showing any output.

Comment: "scan a string input from the user" --> what was the input?

Comment: @chux any string input i give has the same result, btw it was a list of english words.

Comment: @Sappie to input list of words and store into `w1` you need to allocate memory of `w1`, I'm not seeing that in your code. Or you can use a plain simple character buffer like `char w1[1024];`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%s",&w1);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Any returned value other than the number of input format conversion specifiers (in this case '%s') indicates an error occurred.   2) when using the specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
char* w1; /* uninitialized pointer */
scanf("%s",&w1); /* for w1 no memory is allocated. Also & is not required since w1 tends to points to some address */
```

`w` is **character pointer** and *pointer needs to point to some valid memory location*, but in your case `w1` not having any valid memory.

Allocate memory for `w` first and then put the input data into `w` using `scanf()`. For e.g

```
#define BUF_MAX_LENGTH 10

char *w1 = malloc(BUF_MAX_LENGTH);
if(w1 == NULL) {
  /* @TODO error handling */
}
```

And then scan the data into `w1`. For e.g

```
scanf("%s", w1);
```

And once usage is done with `w` do not forget to free the dynamically allocated memory to avoid memory leakage. For e.g

```
free(w1);
```

**Side note**, do avoid declaring character variable & character pointer variable in same declaration to improve code readability. For e.g

```
char* w1,w2,w3,e1,e2,e3; /* mixed up */
```

can be

```
char* w1 = NULL; /* All pointer declaration */
char w2,w3,e1,e2,e3; /* All normal char variable */
```